# Copy and Paste Tables VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a table in excel (range A6:QD16). I have troubles creating a macro that will copy that table and paste it 2 rows below the last row. I would like to add a button. I can copy the table once using record macro but then i have a problem as I have no idea how to make the proces repeat itself.

```
Dim LR As Long
'LR = Last Row
With ActiveSheet
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
End With
MsgBox ("New table will be created in row: " & LR + 2 & vbNewLine & _
"Please wait...")
```

Comment: Are you saying you always want `Range(Cells(6,"A"),Cells(16,"QD"))` copied to the last row + 2, or that you want the same selection to be moved to last row + 2?

Comment: *I can copy the table once using record macro but then i have a problem as I have no idea how to make the proces repeat itself*. OK. Show us the code you're trying to use, and what problem(s) you're having.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just copy and paste a block of data why not use something easy like this:

```
Sub CopyPasteDataBlock()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:QD16").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

To add a button that will execute the code, follow these steps:

1]Select a button
[image]

2]Add button. Right click it and select `Assign Macro` and Map it to the function `CopyPasteTable`
[image]